# jQuery noConflict issue 1.7.0 and 1.10.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I have tried to figure this out for 2 days now reading every post on 10 or 12 sites including this one. Can someone tell me what i did wrong here? I am calling the first jQuery library and implimenting noconflict and still the first jquery plugin will not load.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css"> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var $jq170 = jQuery.noconflict();
</script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.knob.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.ccountdown.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/init.js"></script>

<!--[if lte IE 7]><script src="assets/css/lte-ie7.js"></script><![endif]-->

<!-- Main Jquery & Hover Effects. Should load first -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/hover_pack.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS --> \
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: How are you initializing the code? Most likely you don't even need 2 versions of jQuery but it can be done using the noConflict you are using

Comment: Trying to have two jQuery versions coexist is a recipe for disaster. If you've found an old plugin that won't work with new versions, then the plugin is probably abandonware and it'll just cause you more grief over time.

Comment: @cport1 that is not true. It's not best practice but it most certainly can be done

Comment: This is placed further down in the document.<script>
//enter the count down date using the format year, month, day, time:time
$(".ccounter").ccountdown(2016,12,25,'18:00');
$(".ccounter1").ccountdown(2016,12,25,'18:00');
$(".ccounter2").ccountdown(2016,12,10,'18:00');
</script>

Comment: Anything named `knob.js` *should* be abandoned !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `$` after assigning the first version to `$jq170`.

In order to continue using `$` you would need to do:

```
$jq170(function($){
   /* can use "$" here and it will be the same as "$jq170" */    
});
```

It is most likely that you could use the newer version only and replace the first version so you only include jQuery once in the page.

If plugins are failing in 1.7 when switching to 1.10 it is possible that the `migrate` plugin  may help also. See jQuery downloads